Azure Pipeline - how to prevent circumvention of approval for environment?
Using a YAML-based Azure DevOps Pipeline, how do you require approval to deploy an app service (web app) to an environment such as Production in a way that can't be circumvented by modification of the YAML?
I know that under Pipelines/Environments you can create an environment and set up approvals and checks. Then you can have a stage in the YAML pipeline which is associated with that environment. My concern is that the YAML pipeline could be altered to no longer be associated with that environment (for example change it to the DEV environment which doesn't require approval), but still reference the Production Azure resource (WebAppName property), thereby circumventing the approval. The other thing that limits access seems to be the service connection, but it seems like you need give the pipeline permission to use the service connection, and that doesn't really serve as part of the ongoing approval process per deployment.
- stage: PROD
  displayName: PROD
  jobs:
    - job: Release_Prod
      displayName: Release to PROD
      pool:
        vmImage: 'Windows-2019'
    - deployment:
      displayName: 'PROD Deployment'
      environment: 'Web App - PROD'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current'
                downloadType: 'single'
                artifactName: 'drop'
                downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'Production'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'my-production-web-app'
                package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip'


I figured out how to do it. You don't use environments at all. Instead, you set up the approval on the service connection itself.

Glad that the issue can be resolved, and thanks for sharing the answer. Maybe, you can accept this answer by yourself. It might be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.
